# C# List<> Add lists to dictionary

Tags: c#

```
        Dictionary<string, List<Piese>> SetPiese = new Dictionary<string, List<Piese>>();

        char[] litere = "ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPRSTUVXZ".ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 1; i <= litere.Length; i++) {
            SetPiese.Add(litere[i], Set + litere[i]);
        }

        List<Piese> SetA = GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11);
        List<Piese> SetB = GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2);
        List<Piese> SetC = GenerareSetLitere("C", 1, 5);
        ................................................
```

So I have many lists and I want to add them to a dictionary. How can I do this right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, don't declare them in separate variables to start with. That will always be a pain to work with programmatically. If you'd started with:

```
List<Piese>[] sets = new List<Piese>[]
{
    GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11),
    GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2),
    GenerareSetLitere("C", 1, 5)
    ...
};
```

then you could use:

```
// Note loop condition change
for (int i = 0; i < litere.Length; i++) {
    SetPiese.Add(litere[i], sets[i]);
}
```

Or even better, if `literere` is actually a bunch of expressions you can specify inline, you could do the whole thing in a collection initializer:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Piese>> SetPiese = new Dictionary<string, List<Piese>>
{
    { "first-key", GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11) },
    { "second-key", GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2) }
};
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this works:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Piese>> SetPiese = new Dictionary<string, List<Piese>>();
List<Piese> SetA = GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11);
List<Piese> SetB = GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2);
List<Piese> SetC = GenerareSetLitere("C", 1, 5);
SetPiese.Add("A", SetA);
SetPiese.Add("B", SetB);
SetPiese.Add("C", SetC);
```

I'm not sure because you haven't mentioned the key of your dictionary.

Comment: Yeah It's works but if I have more then 3 lists? You can't ... do SetPiese.Add("ABCDE..XYZ", Set[ABCDEF...XYZ]); 26 times :) @Jon Skeet got it :) Thanks.