# How to add list to dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> sss= new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
List<string> asss = new List<string>();
```

I want to add each element of `asss` to `sss` (part of first key(int) of dictionary)

What can I do for best way?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, don't declare them in separate variables to start with. That will always be a pain to work with programmatically. If you'd started with:

```
List<Piese>[] sets = new List<Piese>[]
{
    GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11),
    GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2),
    GenerareSetLitere("C", 1, 5)
    ...
};
```

then you could use:

```
// Note loop condition change
for (int i = 0; i < litere.Length; i++) {
    SetPiese.Add(litere[i], sets[i]);
}
```

Or even better, if `literere` is actually a bunch of expressions you can specify inline, you could do the whole thing in a collection initializer:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Piese>> SetPiese = new Dictionary<string, List<Piese>>
{
    { "first-key", GenerareSetLitere("A", 1, 11) },
    { "second-key", GenerareSetLitere("B", 9, 2) }
};
```

etc.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695606/c-sharp-list-add-lists-to-dictionary)